# loading symbols into Ghidra after analysis

Tags: ghidra

I have a question about loading symbols.

I have a analyzed a binary and it downloaded relevant symbols for the binary I check from symbol server, and I see for example it does not recognize a parameter as a specific struct from a different library, Is there any option to load another symbols ? (Because in IDA it downloads all relevant symbols ok)

Answer (score 1):

I am going out on a limb here, but if the function in question appears in the datatype archives view (typically bottom left corner of the CodeViewer) with a correct signature, then you probably just need to right click the respective archive and select "Apply Function Datatypes"